# bash curl POST request: "-d" option using a variable

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to make a POST request. The following works without any problem;

```
# Get expected response
curl http://localhost:9020/xxx/xxxx/ -H Content-type:application/json 
-H Accept:application/json -d '{"LED":{ 
"language":"CHINESE"}, "text":"1928年11月22日"}'
```

However, if I try and set the value for the `-d` option curl cannot submit the request to the server.

```
var="{\"LED\":{ \"language\":\"CHINESE\"}, \"text\":\"1928年11月22日\"}"
# No Response
curl http://localhost:9020/xxx/xxxx/ -H Content-type:application/json 
-H Accept:application/json -d $var
```

Can anyone explain why the latter does not seem to work? I have tried a variety of escape characters, but no luck with that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double-quote the variable:

```
curl http://localhost:9020/xxx/xxxx/ -H Content-type:application/json \
-H Accept:application/json -d "$var"
```

Without the double-quoting, the value is split on spaces,
and the shell interprets that as multiple additional arguments to `curl`,
but you need that value to be a single argument.
That's what double-quoting will achieve.

Comment: Thanks - I also came across this as a solution to when passing a variable to a function; should have realized!